# Delete strings from array that do not contain substring

Tags: arrays, swift, string, for-loop

I want to delete the strings from an array that do not contain the substring "originals".
I tried this and it didn't work, it just printed the whole array.  I need like the equivalent of a `for i` loop from Java.

```
for (position, imageURL) in imageURLs.enumerated() {
    if !imageURLs[position].contains("originals"){
        imageURLs.remove(at: position)
    }
}
print(imageURLs)
```

Comment: All you need is `imageURLs = imageURLs.filter { $0.contains("originals") }`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing elements from a sequence while iterating through the sequence is often bug-prone. Consider removing from the collection directly with a predicate:

```swift
imageURLs.removeAll{ !$0.contains("originals") }
```